# Is it possible to use steamcmd to set a build live on a specific Steam branch?

Tags: automation, devops, steam, steamworks-api

I've got a request from one of my developers to automate setting a build live on a specific Steam branch after it's gone through QA on a different branch. The SteamPipe UI makes this very straightforward, but there's got to be a way to do this via CLI.

When we run a build, we use the method described in the documentation where we dynamically create a build script vdf and use the `"SetLive"` flag on the initial testing branch (https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/uploading). Since this is already built, I know there must be a simpler way to just set the build live on a different branch (the SteamPipe UI makes it very easy), but I cannot find the solution. Does anybody have any experience or knowledge about how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall now why this was so difficult to find, but there is a way using the [Steamworks Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps). I just used a curl command to make the call with the appropriate info and it works like a dream. Hope this helps someone out there. :D